# css text on the image

Tags: css, image, text

I have an image which has to take full width. And I need to put a text and a button on top of it in a specific place. I looked over many topics but can not figure out how to make it fully responsive.

```
<div class"wrapper">
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="x">
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
        <h1>text goes there</h1>
        <a>anchor tag goes there</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

so this is the layout but it can be changed if it gets me to the point I need.

If I understand correctly the parent div called wrapper should be set to position: relative and all the child divs to position: absolute, after that you just position all these child elements with top, left, right, bottom. So after testing this this is what I get. Since the image is always 100% of the viewport it gets smaller and smaller by height and width because of its aspect ratio. The text and button on the image just stays at a fixed place and after some point it goes out of the image.

Whats my mistake?

P.S found a lot of topics but still, I am messing something up. Thank you for your insights and help.

Answer (score 0):

The image tag is used to create a separate element on the page. This is not *really* what you want... you want the content-box to have a background, right? Rather than using the image tag, use CSS to apply a background image.

**[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5kekf1c/)**

```css
.content-box {
    /* set width and height to match your image */
    /* if these are omitted, it will only be as big as your content, */
    /* and only show that much of your image */
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    /* obviously, replace this with your image */
    background:url('http://placecage.com/200/300');
}
```

```html
<div class"wrapper">
    <div class="content-box">
        <h1>text goes there</h1>
        <a>anchor tag goes there</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. Also, this is a good occasion to use those HTML5 tags `figure`
and `figcaption`, but basically all you need is this kind of structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img />
    <div class="content-box">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So what is happening here is that your `wrapper`'s dimensions are fixed by the image, and then you position absolutely your `content-box` or the elements within. If you do not want to position them at the very top or bottom of your image, just use percentage values when positionning:

```
top: 10%;
```

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" />
  <figcaption>
    <h1>The image title</h1>
    <p>This is the image caption</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```